# Java GUI : Inputs in textfields change value in other textfield

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Is there a way so that when a user enters values into one textfield and another textfield such as `1` and `1`, a third textfield immediately calculates the sum and displays it without having to add a button to the GUI?

Comment: Yes, lots of ways, depending on the UI framework you intented to use

Comment: In this case I would be using Swing.

Comment: You may register an ActionListener, a KeyListener or a FocusListener on your textfields, depending on your logic.

Comment: @Berger The more appropriate method would be to use a `DocumentListener`, you should avoid using `KeyListener`'s on text components

Comment: [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners)

Comment: @MadProgrammer : right, I totally forgot about this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a document listener to your TextField, that does something on update.

```
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    doSomethingInAnotherTextfield();
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    doSomethingInAnotherTextfield();
  }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    doSomethingInAnotherTextfield();
  }

  public void doSomethingInAnotherTextfield() {
     //whatever you have to do
  }
});
```